# Analyzing 'as' in ascertain, assure, etc

Tags: verbs, adjectives

It seems that in some words, like in the word 'ascertain' or in 'assure', the 'a' or the combination of 'a' and 's' transforms the adjective into a verb. My question is, is there a term in the language for this behavior?

Comment: It's an assimilated form of the Latin preposition and prefix *ad* 'to'.

Comment: It is called prefixion or prefigation. See also: [Change of form of some (Latin) prefixes like ex-, ad- into ef-, a-: are there rules or conditions?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/131373/3036)

Comment: The stereotypic and self-demonstrating example of [assimilation](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/131391/15299); _assimilate_ comes from _ad_ 'toward' + _simil_ 'similar' and the word is produced by assimilating _ad-_ to _simil_, so there is a double S, which was probly pronounced as a long /s/ in Latin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to follow up on the comments by Anonym, Cerberus, and John Lawler, here is the account of the prefix *ad-* in Michael Quinion, *Ologies and Isms: Word Beginnings and Endings* (2002):

> **ad-** *Motion or direction to; reduction or change into; addition, increase, or intensification* {Latin *ad*, to}
>
> Many loanwords from Latin containing this prefix took on a modified or figurative sense in Latin and they retain it in English. [Examples omitted.]
>
> In Latin the prefix changes according to the initial letter of the word to which it is attached—it can appear as **a-** (before *sc* and *sp*), **ac-** (before *c* and *q*), ans as **af-**, **ag-**, **al-**, **ap-**, **ar-**, **as-**, and **at-** in each case before stems beginning with the second letter of the form. [Examples omitted.]

The answers from Cerberus and John Lawler at [Change of form of some (Latin) prefixes like ex-, ad- into ef-, a-: are there rules or conditions?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131373/change-of-form-of-some-latin-prefixes-like-ex-ad-into-ef-a-are-there-ru/131391#131391) address this issue at length, and both concur in calling the phenomenon *assimilation*.

The relevant Merriam-Webster definition of *assimilation* is this one (from the *Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary*):

> change of a sound in speech so that it becomes identical with or similar to a neighboring sound