# What does the prefix "aff" mean?

Tags: meaning, prefixes

What  does the prefix  "***aff***" mean in the following words:

> affine, affirmative, affirm, affable, affection, affluent.

Do they have some meaning in common?

Comment: There's not such root. The original Latin prefix is ad- ("to") which was changed in to af- in assimilation with the first consonant of the root (/f/)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131373/change-of-form-of-some-latin-prefixes-like-ex-ad-into-ef-a-are-there-ru

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on the mistaken notion that *aff-* is a prefix in the English language but it is not, and because even the simplest of research efforts would have quickly revealed this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The common prefix  is  ***ad-*** like in   "[affirmative](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=affirmative&allowed_in_frame=0).":

> - (Modern French affirmer) "affirm, confirm; strengthen, consolidate," from Latin affirmare "to make steady, strengthen," figuratively "confirm, corroborate," ***from  [ad-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ad-)"to" (see ad-) + firmare "strengthen, make firm," from firmus "strong" (see firm (adj.))*** . Spelling refashioned 16c. in French and English on Latin model.

***Ad-***

> - word-forming element expressing direction toward or in addition to, from Latin ad "to, toward" in space or time; "with regard to, in relation to," as a prefix, sometimes merely emphatic.

Etymonline

Comment: _Ad-_, being a prefix, is not generally considered a root; there is no common root to the words listed, only a common prefix.

Comment: are you trying to say that aff is ad ,do these words have something in common like affable,affection ,affluent .@Josh61

Comment: @Boris - the prefix "aff" derives from the prefix "ad" whose meaning is explained in the answer.

Comment: So, "ad-" changes to "af-" when used as a prefix to a word beginning with "f".  The example shown is: "ad-" + "firmare" -> "affirmare"